# Install Ubuntu 10.10 on Virtual Machine

Tags: 10.10, virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 on a virtual machine. I tried VMware Workstation 7.0, VMWare Player 3.0, and Oracle VirtualBox.
I have the same issue on 3 applications, Ubuntu boots very well and logs in to the "test" desktop and everything disappears and the machine reboots again.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: What is the host system?

Comment: Try checking the md5 hash for the image/media?

Comment: This looks like a crash of the virtual machine. For a better understanding of what happens here many more informations on hardware (CPU GPU RAM), host OS and version, settings of the VM are needed.

Comment: The virtual machine settings http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/7523/vmsettingsx.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You may also try pre-installed vdi files.

Check this url:

http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/

At the time being 10.04 is the latest vdi

Comment: I want to test Ubuntu 10.10, maybe I'll go to 10.04 till I find a solution for this issue

Comment: Not recommended.  I tried one of those images, and although it worked, it was in Italian.  I changed the language on it, but it was a hassle. Also, the VM tools needed an update to VirtualBox 4.0 drivers.

Answer (score 1):

From the VM settings you linked to I guess your host runs on Windows. You could try to disable virtual 3D settings.

Second thought: maybe your *.vmdk harddisk has some incompatibilities. Try to generate a new harddisk with a fresh install from an original Ubuntu installation CD image.

Third: Don't try to run a 64-bit (am64) Ubuntu when the host OS is 32-bit only.

Comment: I'm running the VM on Windows 7 64-bit, but I'm trying to install 32-bit Ubuntu

Comment: That's perfectly o.k. this way :-)

Answer (score 1):

try to run it from terminal and give us what they say with copy paste here

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a bad sector on your systems RAM or video card. i would scan the ram on both and see what you see.  if you have onboard video on your system then scanning just the regular system ram is fine i think.

http://www.memtest86.com/